# Excel - If condition with three values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I would like to check three cells, and if the first two are "Yes" then put text in a specific cell, and if all three are "Yes" then different text in that specific cell.

Example:

```
Yes | Yes | No  | "Sort of Working"
Yes | Yes | Yes | "Working
No  | No  | Yes | "Not working"
```

Basically, if all three say Yes then it is "Working" if not, then it is "Not working" by using a formula

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked into the "AND" function?

Comment: I actually tried: =IF(E2="Yes","Not Working","")*IF(F2="Yes","Working","")*IF(G2="Yes","Working","")

Comment: So for your cells, I'd do `=IF(AND(E2="Yes",F2="Yes",G2="Yes"),"Working", "Not Working")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three cells would be about my limit on stacking conditions within an [AND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5F19B2E8-E1DF-4408-897A-CE285A19E9D9). Any more and I would perform a conditional count ([COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34)) and compare the number.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A3, "Yes")=3, "Working", "Not Working")
```

Alternate:

```
=LOOKUP(COUNTIF(A1:A3, "Yes"), {0,1,2,3}, {"Not Working","Not Working","Sort of Working","Working"})
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(COUNTIF(A1:A3, "yes")-1, "Sort of Working","Working"), "Not Working")
```

Comment: I really like your LOOKUP formula you have.  It looks like it will definitely work (theoretically), but I am getting an error trying to use it...

Comment: Thank you @Jeeped ! The =IFERROR formula worked 100%

Comment: I had a round bracket in place of a curly brace in my first post. A subsequent edit fixed that. I've also added a [CHOOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHOOSE-function-fce63190-b514-48cc-a7ff-c1cdaaec0907) alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest [`AND()`](https://support.office.com/en-my/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9) inside of `IF()`.

```
=IF( AND(A1="Yes", A2="Yes", A3="Yes"), "Working", "Not Working" )
```

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Llama .  Do you know if I can add an OR statement in with the IF AND statement by any chance?  To create what I have edited above in the original post.

Comment: Make two different cells.  One checks the first two columns, one checks all three.  `AND()` takes any number of comparisons, so add or remove comparisons as appropriate.

Comment: Sadly I cannot use more columns then what I already have.  It will be used to import into a website, and while I created a Java program for something else in this the formula is just something that has to come from Excel